VisionOS Development - Detect which hand executed the gesture
Is it possible to detect which hand chirality that executed a gesture?
For example,
    TapGesture(count: 2)
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .onEnded { value in
                // if left hand
                    // do something
                // if right hand
                    // do something
            }


I was able to detect hand chirality (kind of) with this hack. However, in order for it to work correctly, only one hand can be seen when this is queried.
func getFirstTrackedHandChirality() async -> HandAnchor.Chirality? {
    for await update in handTracking.anchorUpdates {
        let handAnchor = update.anchor
        guard handAnchor.isTracked else { continue }
        
        if let fingerTip = handAnchor.handSkeleton?.joint(.indexFingerTip) {
            guard fingerTip.isTracked else { continue }
            return handAnchor.chirality
        }
    }
    return nil
}


I do not think SwiftUI offers that information as of visionOS 1.1. You’ll need to use ARKit’s hand tracking APIs if you want to know which hand is gesturing. It will be a substantial amount of work. Start with the ARKit in visionOS documentation and check out the HandTrackingProvider class.

With VisionOS 2 it will be possible using Compositor-Services
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos-release-notes/visionos-2-release-notes#Compositor-Services
SpatialEventGesture

struct ParticlePlayground: View {
    @State var model = ParticlesModel()


    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            for particle in model.particles {
                context.fill(Path(ellipseIn: particle.frame),
                             with: .color(particle.color))
            }
        }
        .gesture(
            SpatialEventGesture()
                .onChanged { events in
                    for event in events {
                        if event.phase == .active { //or chirality

                            // Update particle emitters.
                            model.emitters[event.id] = ParticlesModel.Emitter(
                                location: event.location
                            )
                        } else {
                            // Remove emitters when no longer active.
                            model.emitters[event.id] = nil
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { events in
                    for event in events {
                        // Remove emitters when no longer active.
                        model.emitters[event.id] = nil
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}

